# Can I pass always the full state to reducers?

Tags: redux, react-redux

Is there any inconvenient at all if I design my reducers to, instead of reading only the partial state, had access to the full state tree?

So instead of writing this:

```
function reducer(state = {}, action) {
  return {
    a: doSomethingWithA(state.a, action),
    b: processB(state.b, action),
    c: c(state.c, action)
  }
}
```

I destructure state inside `doSomethingWithA`, `c` or `processB` reducers, separately:

```
function reducer(state = {}, action) {
  return {
    a: doSomethingWithA(state, action), // calc next state based on a
    b: processB(state, action), // calc next state based on b
    c: c(state, action) // calc next state based on a, b and c
  }
}
```

Would I'd be using more RAM? Is there any performance inconvenient? I understand that in javascript, a reference is always passed as parameter, that's why we should return a new object if we want to update the state or use Immutable.JS to enforce immutability, so... again, would it be of any inconvenient at all?

Comment: This is fine from a JS point of view.  However, it implies Redux bad encapsulation.

Comment: and why is it bad, not to encapsulate subcollections in an intended way? I do understand that we atomic reducers that only handle one thing and that they are doing it well, but they are still. With a broader scope to access, so i can keep a flatter structure.

Comment: Because you've introduced coupling between different bits of logic - changing the reducer for B can now affect the behaviour of A.

Comment: Well, by design you are not suppose to change the behaviour of A, unless you are dependant of B output. Which as developer you are responsible of, so it would be a design decision, right? As well as it is to encapsulate state into different collections, which enforce us to write more complex reducers tree.

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily bad: you are still only returning part of the state, but can read anything from the existing state. It all depends on how you're writing the sub-reducers. You lose some of the encapsulation protection that `combineReducers` or your first example give you, but gain more powerful reducers.

Comment: @jsdario - If you're not dependent on B (or one of the other reducers), then why would you pass the whole state to A?  But I agree with OlliM's point - you're trading that against (potentially) simplified reducers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's nothing wrong with that.  Part of the reason for writing update logic as individual functions instead of separate Flux "stores" is that it gives you explicit control over chains of dependencies.  If the logic for updating `state.b` depends on having `state.a` updated first, you can do that.

You may want to read through the [Structuring Reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) section in the Redux docs, particularly the [Beyond `combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/BeyondCombineReducers.html) topic.  It discusses other various reducer structures besides the typical `combineReducers` approach.  I also give some examples of this kind of structure in my blog post [Practical Redux, Part 7: Form Change Handling, Data Editing, and Feature Reducers](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-7-forms-editing-reducers/).